# Звуки в юнити 2D

Tags: c#, аудио, unity3d

Проблема такова. у меня есть код для воспроизведения звука при нажатии A, D, W.

|A - ходьба влево|
|D - ходьба вправо|
|W - прыжок|

не обращайте внимания на названия. мне так удобно.

```
public class aydio : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip kek1;
    public AudioClip kek2;
    private AudioSource audio;

    void Start()
    {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            audio.PlayOneShot(kek1);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            audio.PlayOneShot(kek2);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что звуки ходьбы накладываются друг на друга, и я не знаю как чередовать например 4 звука шага в разном порядке.

**Как сделать случайное чередование звуков ходьбы, чтобы они не накладывались друг на друга и не останавливались пока не кнопку не отпустят.**

плиз, пишите простым языком.

Comment: было бы еще круто если еще сказали бы, как сделать настройку этого звука из игры . и чтобы это сохранялось

Comment: _не обращайте внимания на названия. мне так удобно_ - _kek1, kek2_ - _пишите простым языком_ - Ну-ну. То есть вы будете писать абы как, а вам должны писать понятно.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что я пишу абы как ? "пишите простым языком" я имел виду без сложных понятий, а на простом языке .

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо второго if написать elif

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/714837)